Create a minimalistic Linux similar to a Chromebook
I want to create an ultraligthweight system that only runs a browser. Similar to a Chromebook but using Firefox. Initially I though of installing barebones Xfce, Hyperland or i3wm, and then just install Firefox.
But it got me thinking. Is there a more extreme approach and not install a desktop env? Meaning, do something like startx and just open Firefox without any "proper" desktop
I was thinking of using Fedora or Arch to achieve this. Any thoughts on how to achieve this?

Thanks to @doneal24 suggestion of installing a kiosk distro. I was able to find the keyword to create the minimalistic environment I was looking for. I ended up installing Cage. It's very lightweight and runs on Wayland.
Basically I installed wayland and it's dependencies, cage and firefox.
sudo dnf install cage wroots xorg-x11-server-Xwayland mesa-va-drivers

After that I just launched cage and got firefox.
cage firefox


If my answer resolved your issue, please consider accepting the answer. The aids in future searches (along with increasing my reputation score).

It looks like you are looking at fairly complete distributions. Have you considered something like damsmalllinux as a starting point?There are also kiosk systems like Porteous that might need your needs. What research have you done to examine alternatives?

Never heard of those. Porteus looks good. Although it seems that it has some sort of pricing attach to it for updates. I guess is just if you don't want to do it manually. I did some research on some distros and is not easy since in most cases the suggestion is any distro with Xfce or LXDE. Basically they always come with a full desktop. Haven't been able to find more distros like Porteus. I guess is the query I'm using. I know Arch and Fedora are big but they come with lots of support and "security"
